Smooth convex function where convolution with Gaussian is never finite
My background is in computer science, and I often find results involving convolutions stated without sufficient assumptions. For instance, I saw somewhere a result which seemed to make the following claim.
Claim: When $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and convex, and $g$ is the standard Gaussian density, then the convolution $f*g$ is always finite valued.
This claim struck me as odd, since in mathematics one typically needs to make some assumption about the decay of the function at infinity, in order to ensure that the convolution is well defined (the most canonical one is that $f$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$).
To formalize this, I propose the following counterexample to the claim. Consider the function $f(x) = e^{x^2}$. Since this function is twice differentiable (indeed, it is smooth), a calculation shows that $f'' \geq 1$ everywhere, implying that $f$ is strongly convex. Then we just note for any fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that
$$
f*g(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} e^{(x-y)^2} e^{-y^2 / 2} dy \geq \frac{e^{x^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{y \geq 4x + 2} e^y dy = \infty.
$$
Can someone who is familiar with these topics please confirm that my counterexample is correct?
As a followup, I do want to confirm that while we typically assume $f$ is integrable, this is certainly not necessary to ensure that $f *g$ is finite valued right? For instance, if $f$ was Lipschitz globally, but not integrable, then I think $f*g$ should always be finite valued (again $g$ is the standard Gaussian density).

This claim is obviously false. Letting $b$ be the minimum of the Gamma function on the positive real line, consider $f(x)=\Gamma(\operatorname{sgn}(x)\cdot x+b)$

Your counterexample is essentially correct, but you'll actually want $y \ge \max(0, 4 x + 2)$, not just $y \ge 4 x + 2$.
Yes, $f$ globally Lipschitz would do it, or more generally $|f(x)|$ bounded by a polynomial in $|x|$.

thank you, that's what i thought. basically we are controlling the growth of the function at infinity. thanks!
